# Reshaping pandas dataframe (dissolving subclass)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first post so please be kind :P

I am currently working on pandas in python 3.7.

The aim is to reshape a datraframa by dissolving the "subclass" methods (M1, M2, Mn).

This is my starting point:

```
(0, 'gas', 'M1', 0.50)
(0, 'gas', 'M2', 0.49)
(1, 'coal', 'M1', 0.80)
(1, 'coal', 'M2', 0.81)
(2, 'wind', 'M1', 0.34)
(2, 'wind', 'M2', 0.94)
```

From following source code data:

```
[{'ID': 0,'type': 'gas', 'Method': 'M1',
  'Score': 0.50},{'ID': 0,'type': 'gas', 'Method': 'M2',
  'Score': 0.80},{'ID': 1,'type': 'coal', 'Method': 'M1',
  'Score': 0.81},{'ID': 1,'type': 'coal', 'Method': 'M2',
  'Score': 0.49},{'ID': 2,'type': 'wind', 'Method': 'M1',
  'Score': 0.34},{'ID': 2,'type': 'wind', 'Method': 'M2',
  'Score': 0.94}]
```

which gets loaded into a pandas dataframe by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["ID","type", "Method", "Score"])
```

creating following structure:

```
ID  type    Method   Score

0   gas      M1      0,50
0   gas      M2      0,49
1   coal     M1      0,80
1   coal     M2      0,81
2   wind     M1      0,34
2   wind     M2      0,94
```

Unltimately I would like to achive the following format:

```
ID   type     M1     M2

0    gas     0,50   0,49 
1    coal    0,80   0,81
2    wind    0,34   0,94
```

Since the amount of methods can vary, a simple cut and paste will probably not do the job.
Any feedback would be helpful!
Thanks :)

Comment: kindly share the source code data : ``df.to_dict('records')``

Comment: something like `dfp = df.pivot(index='type', columns='Method', values='Score').reset_index()`  and `dfp.columns.name = None`. Alternatively, do `index=['ID', 'type']` instead of `index='type'`.

Comment: Thank you @TrentonMcKinney !